# jQuery delay() or setTimeout()

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Please if you could help me; I need to open a link in new tab (or window), but only after executing a few functions. I tried everything, pure JavaScript, jQuery, nothing works.
It doesn't matter to me if the solution provided is with `delay()` or with `setTimeout(`).
I think that the problem with `delay()` is that it only works with functions in fx queue, I tried something, but just can't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){

   $(“#playNowLink”).click(function() {

   $(‘#header’).effect(“fold”, { size: “50%” }, 1000);

   $(‘#showVideo’).delay(1100).fadeIn(‘slow’);

   // Here I would like to call ‘playNow.html’,
   //but only after 7-8 seconds


});
```

Comment: Careful of your curly quotes...

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function(){

   //whatever the heck you want do to:

   //open window:
   window.open('new_window_url');

   //change location?
   window.location = "new_location_url";

}, 7500); //7.5 seconds
```

Comment: Oh boy, do i feel stupid now.Wasting my time with delay(), and when i was trying with setTimeout i never passed anonymous function into it,instead i was using some code from some blog, which was obviously not good.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is your missing line:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.open('playNow.html');}, 7000);
```

But I liked Matijs' idea of putting it in the animation callback.

Comment: Your code works, but i was trying with this, and it doesn't work.I thought it was the same thing.setTimeout("window.location.href('playNow.html')", 7000);

Comment: You asked about opening it in a new window or tab - for that use `window.open`. If you want to redirect the current window, use `window.location.href`. Mind you, the correct syntax is `window.location.href = "playNow.html"`.

Comment: Never use quotes for the function, triggers eval()

Comment: @mcp: This was a perfectly good answer, with useful comments pinning the OP's bug. Anyhow, thanks to you, now it's even better - without `eval` :) (I think an upvote is in order...)

Answer (score 0):

This javascript should work - what issue are you having with it?

```
setTimeout('changeLocation()',7000);
function changeLocation()
{
    window.location="playNow.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback of `.fadeIn()` like so

`.fadeIn('slow', function() { // do this after the fade in completes });`