# How to write delay in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually My Script is

```
var i=0;
while(i <  folder.length) 
{   

  $("#hide_message").load('/fdc.php?path='+encodeURIComponent(folder[i]) );  

  //Delay After 10 Sec  
  $("#hide_message").load('/member.php?path='+encodeURIComponent(folder[i]) ); 
  //Delay After 10 Sec  

    i++;
}
```

Is this possible to make delay every line in jquery.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the delay..?

Comment: Better design would be to delay the thing that calls that code. Rather than separate delays for every piece of jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Please go through the following questions(and it's answers), here in stackoverflow.

[delay() and .setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882328/jquery-delay-or-settimeout)

[jQuery delay and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407935/delay-and-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
//your action code                
},1000*10);
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is possible.

Take a look into the jquery API document.

https://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
var i=0;
while(i <  folder.length) 
{   

  $("#hide_message").load('/fdc.php?path='+encodeURIComponent(folder[i]) );  

  //Delay After 10 Sec  
  $("#hide_message").delay(1000).load('/member.php?path='+encodeURIComponent(folder[i]) ); 
  //Delay After 10 Sec  

    i++;
}
```

You can try this. But I didn't test it!

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Comment: you can't use it in a loop to make a javascript delay

Comment: Ah.. Didn't see the loop! Sry!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this:

```
var i = 0;
while(i <  folder.length) {   
    var index = i;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#hide_message").load('/fdc.php?path=' + encodeURIComponent(folder[index]));  
    }, i * 1000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#hide_message").load('/member.php?path=' + encodeURIComponent(folder[index])); 
    }, (i + 1) * 1000);

    i++;
}
```

Using this way none of those AJAX loadings coincide.

**Note:** You shouldn't pass `i` as an index to `folder` array. You should instead declare a local variable and pass it. `var index = i;`. The why would be some side effects of JavaScript closure.